# How to write an async RPC client with Pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, rpc, pika

I'm trying to write an async RPC client using pika, I'm basing my code on the following example,

http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.html

The problem is that according to pika's [RPC blocking example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html), a RPC call does not use an exchange, however whenever I try to open an exchange using,

```
self._channel.exchange_declare(self.on_exchange_declareok,
                                   '',
                                   self.EXCHANGE_TYPE)
```

I get disconnected. Also, if I try to skip the exchange_declare function and jump right into declaring the queue, I get the same result. What is the proper way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement an Async RPC client by adding a background thread that handles the RabbitMQ connection. I have a working example for pika and flask available [here](https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py).

You also have an a little more elaborate example that is based on my own library available [here](https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/blob/master/examples/flask_threaded_rpc_client.py).

These are obviously still based on the Blocking Connection, but at least they offer an asynchronous solution.